# How to use EF core owned entites

Tags: entity-framework

I am using a SQLite database EFCore 2.0 preview in UWP Project.
 The address table is split into to different entities

Delivery address,
Invoice Address
    using

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().OwnsOne(p => p.DeliveryAddress);
```

which works great for setting up the database, with migrations, creates the different table in the database. With test data that I have put in manually works great at reading data from these tables. But how do I save changes to the DeliveryAddress table. Nothing is getting persisted to the database, when I save the using:

```
public void UpdateDeliveryAddress(Project modifiedProject)
{
    using (var db = new SteelFrameCalculatorDataContext())
    {
        db.Entry(modifiedProject).State = EntityState.Modified;

        db.SaveChanges();   
    }
}
```

Project being the parent entity

> 2017-06-11T23:21:10.9242463+01:00 Warning 8 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation
>   The key {'ProjectId'} on entity type 'Project.DeliveryAddress->Address' contains properties in shadow state - {'ProjectId'}. To configure this warning use the DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings API (event id 'CoreEventId.ModelValidationShadowKeyWarning'). ConfigureWarnings can be used when overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or using AddDbContext on the application service provider.

Using the following allowed in to save updates to the database. Assume the UpdateRange(entity) sets all to modified. Not sure if this is the correct way, but it works.

```
using (var db = new SteelFrameCalculatorDataContext())
{               

                db.UpdateRange(modifiedProject);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the state of the child object? Looks like you're only setting the parent `Project` state.

Adding this should do it:

```
db.Entry(modifiedProject.DeliveryAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: When i added this line i got a error 
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The entity type 'Address' has delegated identity and the given entity is currently not being tracked. To start tracking this entity call '.Reference().TargetEntry' on the owner entry.
  
By using 

using (var db = new SteelFrameCalculatorDataContext())
            {
                
                db.UpdateRange(modifiedProject);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }

Comment: I'm not positive, but that sounds like one of the objects in the tree needs to be attached to your context. As I understand it, you need to manage adding/attachment & state of all your child elements as changes dont flow down from parents.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Entry(modifiedProject).Reference(a=>a.DeliveryAddress).TargetEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.